# Ng-repeat items do not have $$hash key which messing up with the render

Tags: angularjs

I have this code for ng-repeat:

```
<div class="col-12 note-list-item"
     ng-repeat="data in viewModels track by data.id + data.title"
     ng-click="edit(data.id)"
     ontouchstart="touchStart()" ontouchend="touchEnd()" 
     ontouchmove="touchMove()">
    <p ng-class="deleteMode ? 'note-list-title w-80' : 'note-list-title'" ng-bind-html="data.title"></p>
    <p ng-class="deleteMode ? 'note-list-date w-80' : 'note-list-date'">{{data.dateCreated | displayDate}}</p>
    <div ng-if="deleteMode" class="note-list-delete ease-in" ng-click="delete($event, data.id)">
        <span class="btn fa fa-trash"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

There is a problem with the rendering. Every time I update the list (viewModels) by replacing the array, the html element renders a duplicate for a brief millisecond then match the new array. This causes blinking when I update the list.

After thorough checking, I find out that there is no `$$hashKey` in the items.

This is how I load the list:

```
$scope.loadViewModels = function (orderBy, table, cb) {
    if (!$scope.endOfPage) {
        let searchKey = $scope.page.searchString;
        let skip = ($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.itemsPerPage;
        let searchClause = '';

        if (searchKey && searchKey.length > 0) {
            let searchArr = [];
            $($scope.vmKeys).each((i, key) => {
                searchArr.push(key + ` LIKE '%` + searchKey + `%'`);
            });
            searchClause = `WHERE ` + searchArr.join(' OR ');
        }

        let sc = `SELECT * FROM ` + table + ` ` + searchClause + ` ` + orderBy +
            ` LIMIT ` + skip + `, ` + $scope.itemsPerPage;
        sqlite.query(sc, rows => {
            $scope.$apply(function () {
                var data = [];
                let loadedCount = 0;
                if (rows != null) {
                    $scope.currentPage += 1;
                    loadedCount = rows.length;
                    if (rows.length < $scope.itemsPerPage)
                        $scope.endOfPage = true

                    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                        let item = rows.item(i);
                        let returnObject = {};
                        $($scope.vmKeys).each((i, key) => {
                            returnObject[key] = item[key];
                        });
                        data.push(returnObject);
                    }

                    //REPLACING THE ARRAY
                    if ($scope.viewModels != null)
                        $scope.viewModels = $scope.viewModels.concat(data);
                    else
                        $scope.viewModels = data;
                }
                else
                    $scope.endOfPage = true;

                if (cb)
                    cb(loadedCount);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: where do you replace the array? please post the code

Comment: I commented in the code //REPLACING THE ARRAY, please kindly check it

Comment: You do not have `$$hashKey` because you use a `track by`.

Comment: You are correct, the real problem is the render here. It creates duplicates for a brief millisecond each time the list got updated. I read that I need to use track by, but that does not help. I tried various track by, but the dupes still there then vanished after some milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Change `$apply` to `$applyAsync`:

```js
let sc = `SELECT * FROM ` + table + ` ` + searchClause + ` ` + orderBy +
    ` LIMIT ` + skip + `, ` + $scope.itemsPerPage;
sqlite.query(sc, rows => {
    ̶$̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶$̶a̶p̶p̶l̶y̶(̶f̶u̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶(̶)̶ ̶{̶
    $scope.$applyAsync(function () {
            
            // ...

            //REPLACING THE ARRAY
            if ($scope.viewModels != null)
                $scope.viewModels = $scope.viewModels.concat(data);
            else
                $scope.viewModels = data;
        }
        else
            $scope.endOfPage = true;

        if (cb)
            cb(loadedCount);
    });
});
```

That way changes to `$scope` for each row gets consolidated into one browser tick.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $scope/$roootScope API Reference - $applyAsync](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$applyAsync)